# How would I check for allevenbits in bitwise operations?

Tags: bit-manipulation, bit, bitwise-operators

Using bitwise operations exclusively, how would I set y to 1 if all even-numbered bits of x are 1, and otherwise y is set to 0 (maximum of 8-bits)?

So far I have as follows:

```
p = ~x + 1
a = p >> 2
b = p >> 4
c = p >> 6
d = p >> 8
y = [insert code here]
```

Permitted: 12 operations (may use `!`, `~`, `+`, `-`, `<<`, `>>`, `&`, `^`, `|`) and up to 8-bit constants.

Comment: What about the odd bits?

Comment: `~x + 1` seems strange in this context, why do we have that?

Comment: @harold I agree - and `p >> 8` on an 8 bit number looks strange too.

Comment: @harold i removed that from my code, as it actually is redundant. i just added that to ensure that it was an unsigned integer

Comment: @TedLyngmo yeah, idk what i was thinking there

Comment: @L4w1i3t :-) Did you have any luck with my suggestion on how to do it?

Comment: I tried using it, and what comes up is that both variables will always be 11111111. . ._2 (or -1) for uneven. for even, y = 1, but the even bits for x are 0.

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't sound right. There is  only one bit that _can_ be set so I wonder how you managed to get that result. What programming language are you using? Are you ok if I show you that it works in a C program?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251666/discussion-between-l4w1i3t-and-ted-lyngmo).

Answer (score 0):

You could shift down all bits to the first bit and do a bitwise AND:

```
#even
y = 1 & (x >> 6) & (x >> 4) & (x >> 2) & x

#odd
y = (x >> 7) & (x >> 5) & (x >> 3) & (x >> 1)
```

Note the `1 &` part for the even case since `x >> 6` leaves the 2 MSbs in the result and you only want the low one.

Here's a demonstrative program in written in C:
[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/coexbMf7b)

---

Since you mentioned that you may use `!` (NOT), a simpler version may be:

```
#even
!((x & 0b01010101) ^ 0b01010101)

#odd
!((x & 0b10101010) ^ 0b10101010)
```

Here the constants are first used to filter out the even/odd bits and then XOR with the same. This will produce `0` if all bits were set. Combine with NOT and you'll get `1` if they were all set and `0` if they were not.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/cTbnWrzKT)